How to us OR AND conditions in CLI --testMeta
We wanted to see how to do OR condition mainly in CLI --testMeta
For example it i have a test with tag as initiative: A and another test with tag initiative: B, how to i do a OR in CLI --testMeta to run both test cases, please help

The --test-meta option doesn't support the OR condition. However, you can try to filter tests by Metadata and a function in .testcaferc.js. Please refer the following example for information on how to Filter Tests By Metadata.
Regarding the AND condition, you need to list all parameters separated by commas, as suggested in the documentation
